# Minor Gradle upgrade breaks test compilation

Tags: gradle, groovy

I want to incrementally upgrade the Gradle wrapper in order to improve build speed. After moving from 2.3 to 2.4 the test compilation fails with an `incompatible types` error and I am struggling with dependencies.

Consider this Spock test:

```java
class DetailsSortKeySpec extends Specification {
    def 'Simple Test'() {
        given:
        TestDetailsSortKey testDetailsSortKey = new TestDetailsSortKey(details, collationKey)

        expect:
        testDetailsSortKey.details.equals(details)

        where:
        details                | collationKey
        new TestDetails(id: 0) | Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).getCollationKey('')
    }

    private class TestDetailsSortKey extends DetailsSortKey<TestDetails> {
        TestDetailsSortKey(TestDetails details, CollationKey collationKey) {
            super(details, collationKey)
        }
    }
}
```

And this Java class:

```java
public class DetailsSortKey<T extends Details> {

    private final T details;
    private final CollationKey collationKey;

    public DetailsSortKey(final T details, final CollationKey collationKey) {
        this.details = details;
        this.collationKey = Objects.requireNonNull(collationKey);
    }

    public final T getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
}
```

Following error message appears when running `compileTestGroovy`:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/gradle_upgrade/build/tmp/compileTestGroovy/groovy-java-stubs/com/vendor/transfer/sorting/DetailsSortKeySpec.java:25: error: incompatible types: Details cannot be converted to TestDetails
super ((com.vendor.common.transfer.Details)null, (java.text.CollationKey)null);
       ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
startup failed:
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

1 error

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':WEB-Commons:compileTestGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The [Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/release-notes.html#known-issues) do not list any issues that seem to be responsible for this, so I dug through Groovy Issues that could be the root cause and for real found an [issue about Generics](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7015). But the bug should already be fixed. I do not understand where and why there is a try to covert `Details` to `TestDetails`, which is just a plain and empty derivation from the `Details` class.

These are the used Groovy versions in both Gradle distros:

**Gradle 2.3**: Groovy: 2.3.9

**Gradle 2.4**: Groovy 2.3.10

To me, this seems exactly like the referenced Groovy bug, but that one should be fixed since 2.3.8 and should not affect this build. Furthermore, the dependencies are declared as followed in the project:

```
dependencies {
    // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"
}
```

And the difference between the output of both `gradlew :dependencies` do only contain tools, that are mentioned in the release notes but do not belong to the test scope.

Eventually, which Groovy version is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wanting to compile with a different version of Groovy than the one bundled with Gradle. See [GroovyCompile.groovyClasspath](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile:groovyClasspath)

Eg:

```
configurations {
    groovy
}
dependencies {
    groovy 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11'
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}
compileGroovy {
    groovyClasspath = configurations.groovy
}
```

*** Edit ***

To see what version is being picked (due to dependency resolution) you can

```
gradle dependencies
```

Or (where xxx is a subproject name)

```
gradle xxx:dependencies
```

To force a specific dependency version you can

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11'
    }   
}
```

See [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)

Comment: That didn't do the trick. That way I could force it to use Groovy 2.3, which is the one bundled with Gradle indeed. It broke with a version mismatch error. That's proving my attempt uses not the bundled Groovy, but the one I reference. Question is - why does it still break?

Comment: Perhaps you have another dependency bringing in the `groovy-all` dependency. Try `gradle dependencies` (or `gradle xxx:dependencies` for a subproject) to see what's happening. You might need to force the version (see my update)

Comment: That's why I have no clue what's going on here. Kind of sorcery... but neither Groovy changed apparently, nor were there any changes between these Gradle version, that should mess with my tests.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.14.1, which build completely fine... Anyway, as this seems to be some kind of sorcery, I accept your answer as it provided helpful strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Spock has a transitive dependency on `groovy-all` which might be conflicting with the `groovy-all` version you are declaring. Also you are not using Gradle's version of `groovy-all` (you are declaring yet another version of this). I declare those two dependencies differently, like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}
```

Comment: Since these dependencies are not changed at all, I doubt this will have any impact. Furthermore, it isn't always a good idea to reference the bundled Groovy distribution, is it? Spock-for-Groovy-2.4 could then face Groovy 2.3 and break.

Comment: It depends on your distinction of "bundled Groovy distribution", bundled with Spock? or bundled with Gradle? I'm using the version bundled with Gradle

Comment: What happens, when Gradle comes with e.g. Groovy 1.9 Or 3.1? That's what I mean with not being a good idea to reference the bundled one. You want to use the specific version that works with your dependency, correct?

Comment: I always want to use the groovy version bundled with gradle since I only write gradle plugins or spock tests in groovy. Everything else is java, I never deploy Groovy code to production. Please see my other answer to use your own version of Groovy for compilation

Comment: Thanks, but I can only use these statements in the configuration phase, because of the compilation error - and that outputs the bundled Groovy version then. Cannot execute any code in the test. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe if you switch on debugging (`-d` or `--debug`) you could see the command line being invoked for the groovy compile step. Perhaps that might lead you towards the cause?